# Stacking of 2 convolutional layers

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

In a convolutional layer with n neurons, trained for inputs with dimension h x w x c (height x width x channel), c usually being 3 (RGB), one trains n x c kernels of size k x k (and n bias values). So for each neuron i in the layer and each channel j in the input, we have a weight matrix of size k x k, we call weights_ij. The output of each neuron i=1,..,n (for input X) is as follows:

out_i = sigma ( tmp_i + bias_i)

with tmp_i = sum_{j=1,...,c} conv(X, weights_ij).

The output is then h_new x w_new x n. So basically the depth of the output coincides with the number of neurons in the first layer. h_new and w_new depend on padding and stride in the convolution.
This makes sense to me and I also checked it by coding the convolution and the summation myself and comparing the result with the result of a keras model, that only consists of this one layer. Now my acutal question: when we add a second convolutional layer, my understanding was that the output from the first layer is now a "picture" with n channels and we do exactly the same as before but with c=n (and a new number n2 of neurons in our 2nd layer).

But I also coded that and compared it with the prediction of a keras model with 2 convolutional layers and now the result is not the same. So does anyone know how the 2nd convolutional layer treats the output of the first?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem.
Actually the problem was already present for just one layer and by stacking 2 layers the errors accumulated.

I thought when using stride=2 in the convolutional layer, one applys the convolution to the sections [0:N_k,0:N_k], [2:2+N_k,2:2+N_k], [4:4+N_k,4:4+N_k],... of the input but keras actually applys the convolution to [1:1+N_k,1:1+N_k], [3:3+N_k,3:3+N_k],...

Comment: for odd input dimensions height and width and for padding="same".